# ¿Cómo detectar y reemplazar un carácter extraño en PHP?

Tags: php, php7, firebird, firebird2.5

Estoy haciendo un SCRIPT en PHP cuya función es migrar bases de datos Paradox a Firebird, a través de ficheros CSV (Esto no aporta nada, pero para ponerlos en contexto).

Hay un caso excepcional donde debo leer una tabla (vamos a llamarle X) cuyo campo "DESCRIPCIÓN" tiene el nombre de las columnas de otra tabla (vamos a llamarle Y), independientemente si el diseño está bien o no, el problema que se me presenta es el siguiente:

Los datos que se guardan en el campo DESCRIPCIÓN de la tabla X tienen caracteres extraños, específicamente **ª**.

Aquí les dejo una screenshot de el campo en cuestión:

[image: Columna DESCRIPCIÓN de la tabla X]
¿Cuál es el problema? que mi script al coger eso e intentar hacer un ALTER TABLE Y ADD $valor donde $valor es el dato que está en el campo "DESCRIPCIÓN" de la tabla X, explota.

Luego de coger los datos del CSV los "filtro un poco", en el caso de los string hace lo siguiente: `return utf8_encode("'".utf8_decode($val)."'"); //String`

Aunque tampoco quiero estar manipulando datos, ya que, se trata de una migración. Todo debe quedar igual.

¿Alguna sugerencia para que no me explote?

```
Detalles del error: PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: -104 Dynamic SQL Error SQL error code = -104 Token unknown - line 1, column 28 'T? Cam. Congelados (C1) A' in C:\xampp\htdocs\script.php:305 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\script.php(305): PDO->exec('ALTER TABLE Y...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\script.php(62): autodump('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...', 'miBD', Array) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\script.php(40): start() #3 {main}.
```

PD: He recortado la imagen intencionalmente.

Comment: Parece el típico problema del encoding. No tengo muy claro que los datos que la tabla origen estén en UTF-8. Problablemente con otro encoding lo tendrías resuelto

Comment: ¿Por qué usas `utf8_decode()` y vuelves a codificar con `utf8_encode`? Si `$val` está en otra codificación de 1 solo caracter no necesitas `utf8_decode()`. Creo que lo más apropiado es usar [iconv()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.iconv.php), proporcionando codificación de entrada y salida. Finalmente, ¿por qué encierras el valor entre comillas simples?

Comment: *(Esto no aporta nada, pero para ponerlos en contexto).* Puede que sí aporte y que además sea la clave de todo. Hay un evidente problema de codificación y conviene resolverlo al nivel más bajo posible, aunque empieces a depurar en el sentido contrario. Establece utf-8 en todos los niveles: entorno HTML, entorno PHP, conexión a la BD, datos en la BD, codificación en el archivo CSV. Ve controlando/definiendo la codificación en ese orden y llegarás a la solución del problema. Usar funciones de codificación sobre cada dato, además de tedioso, suele ser inútil en estos casos.